# String getting converted to number when inserting it in database through Perl's DBI $sth->execute() function

Tags: perl, sqlite, type-conversion, dbi, dbd

I'm using Perl's DBI and SQLite database (I have DBD::SQLite installed). I have the following code:

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:SQLite:dbname=$db", "", "", { RaiseError => 1, AutoCommit => 1 });
...
my $q = "INSERT OR IGNORE INTO books (identica, book_title) VALUES (?, ?)";
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($q);
$sth->execute($book_info->{identica}, $book_info->{book_title});
```

The problem I have is when `$book_info->{identica}` begins with 0's they get dropped and I get a number inserted in the database.

For example, `identica` of `00123` will get converted to `123`.

I know SQLite doesn't have types, so how do I make DBI to insert the `identica` as string rather than number?

I tried quoting it as `"$book_info->{identica}"` when passing to `$sth->execute` but that didn't help.

**EDIT**

Even if I insert value directly in query it doesn't work:

```
my $i = $book_info->{identica};
my $q = "INSERT OR IGNORE INTO books (identica, book_title) VALUES ('$i', ?)";
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($q);
$sth->execute($book_info->{book_title});
```

This still coverts `00123` to `123`, and `0000000009` to `9`...

**EDIT**

Holy sh*t, I did this on the command line, and I got this:

```
sqlite> INSERT INTO books (identica, book_title) VALUES ('0439023521', 'a');
sqlite> select * from books where id=28;
28|439023521|a|
```

It was dropped by SQLite!

Here is how the schema looks:

```
CREATE TABLE books (
  id                INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  identica          STRING  NOT NULL,
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IDX_identica       on books(identica);
CREATE INDEX IDX_book_title            on books(book_title);
```

Any ideas what is going on?

**SOLUTION**

It's sqlite problem, see answer by in the comments by Jim. The `STRING` has to be `TEXT` in sqlite. Otherwise it treats it as number!

Changing schema to the following solved it:

```
CREATE TABLE books (
  id                INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  identica          TEXT  NOT NULL,
);
```

Comment: What is the declaration (i.e. type affinity) of that column in SQLite?  According to the docs, if it's `TEXT` it should store it as a string; otherwise it will be a number.

Comment: @JimGarrison Please see the updated question. I'm using `STRING`. Let me try `TEXT`.

Comment: @JimGarrison You just saved my day. I converted it to `TEXT` and it works perfectly!

Comment: I posted my suggestion as an answer

Comment: Note also that in sqlite, `integer primary key autoincrement` is not needed--each table has an implicit `rowid` column.

Answer (score 3):

Use [bind params](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.618/DBI.pm#bind_param)

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($q);
$sth->bind_param(1, 00123, { TYPE => SQL_VARCHAR });
$sth->bind_param(2, $book_info->{book_title});
$sth->execute();
```

**UPDATE:**

Read about [type affinity in SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html). Because your column type is `STRING` (technically unsupported), it defaults to INTEGER affinity. You need to create your column as `TEXT` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried this but it didn't help. I did more experiments and please see my updated question. It looks like sqlite3 is dropping leading 0's it all by itself!

Comment: Thanks. Please leave your original answer as it was insightful as well. Please combine both answers!

Comment: Added the original answer back in. Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs, if the column type (affinity) is TEXT it should store it as a string; otherwise it will be a number.